# How to use scraped data from website to Word2vec Gensim

Tags: python, mysql, gensim, word2vec

I'm pretty new to MySQL, Gensim, and Word2Vec, and I'm still learning how to use by working on my personal project.

I have data that I got by doing web scraping so it's not hard coded.
(I used Instagram account to get hashtag data from several post, so my data is
Instagram hashtags)

I'm trying to use that data in this code below:

```
import pymysql.cursors
import re
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host=secrets[0],
user=username,
password=password,
db='test',
charset='charsetExample',
cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    # connection to database
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # cursor is iterator / 'Select' - caption is column 
     # post is the table 
     cursor.execute("SELECT caption FROM posts LIMIT 1000")
     data = cursor.fetchall()
     # list of captions
      captions = [d['caption'].lower() for d in data]
     # hashtags = [re.findall(r"#([A-Za-z_0-9]+)", caption) for caption in captions]
    # hashtags = [hashtag for hashtag in hashtags if hashtag != []]
    model = Word2Vec(captions, min_count=1)
    model = Word2Vec(hashtags) 
    res = model.wv.most_similar("fitness")

    print(captions)
    print(res)

finally:
    connection.close()
```

This is the part that I'm working on and not really sure how to do:

```
res = model.wv.most_similar("fitness")
```

For now I was trying to use `most_similar()` method to see how it works.
What I'm trying to do is in the `most_similar("value")` I want to use my data
which will be each hashtags that I got by scraping the Instagram website as the value.

Thank you!

Comment: So basically, you want to get the most similar hashtags?

Comment: Yes, but my main problem is how do I use the data(hashtag from user's account) that I got as value. Hope this make sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so, You have to train the word2vec model yourself. What you have to do is make sure that your hashtags are actually without `#` sign and lowercase.

Now, group the hashtags by post. So, if some post had hashtags `#red`, `#Wine`, `#party`, you should make a list from it to look like: `[red, wine, party]`. Repeat that for every post and save a list from every post to a new list. So the output from this should be list of lists: `[[red, wine, party], [post_2_hashtags], ...]`. Now you can input that to the word2vec model and train it with this line:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(
    documents,
    size=150,
    window=10,
    min_count=2,
    workers=10)
model.train(documents, total_examples=len(documents), epochs=10)
model.save("word2vec.model")
```

`documents` is a list of lists created in the previous step. You can then load the model with `model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model")`. And the rest is the same. You still use `most_similar()` method to get the most similar word (in this case, hashtag).

The only thing you have to be aware of is the vector size (`size` parameter in `word2vec.model`). You define it before training. If you have a lot of data, you set it to be a bigger number, and if you have smaller amount of data, set it to smaller number. But this is something you have to figure out since you're the only one that can see the data you have. Try playing with the `size` parameter and evaluate the model with `most_similar()` method.

I hope this is clear enough :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I made a txt file that stores hashtag data that I got by web scrapping. Then I was trying follow your solution, but I got error ` model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(
NameError: name 'gensim' is not defined` and I checked if gensim is installed correctly in several different ways and it does.. So I'm stuck here again...

Comment: I suppose you have imported it?

Comment: Omg... I'm sorry, I thought I did, I just did so no longer getting the same error again, but I have another question to ask you. So now that I have hashtag.txt(example file name for the hashtag lists I saved in) under same folder that I have my gensim code, I thought what I need to do is set that text file as to my document like (document = 'textfilename.txt') however I'm keep getting I'm getting name 'documents' is not defined or 
: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'documents' .. I think I'm missing or not understanding something..

Comment: You should open the `txt` file and read it to some variable and then pass it to the model like this:  `with open('hashtags.txt', 'r') as f: tags = f.read()` and then pass it to the model like: `documents=tags`